# Old GCC can not automatically find the new version libstdc++?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, undefined-reference, libstdc++

I'm trying to use the 3rd-party lib, called DocToText, with gcc 4.4.7.

I compiled the program with:

`g++ -I./doctotext/ -L./doctotext/ -Wl,-rpath=./doctotext -ldoctotext  -o example test_doctotext.cpp`

In the beginning, it returned `libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found`

I manually downloaded the newer version, and re-linked, here is the result

```
[root@mail]~xian# find / -name "libstdc++.so.6"
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
[root@mail]~xian# strings /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
[root@mail]~xian# strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
```

But when I compiled again, it returned:

```
[root@mail]~xian# g++ -I./doctotext/ -L./doctotext/ -Wl,-rpath=./doctotext -ldoctotext -o example test_doctotext.cpp 
./doctotext//libdoctotext.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::swap(std::__detail::_List_node_base&, std::__detail::_List_node_base&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
./doctotext//libdoctotext.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
./doctotext//libdoctotext.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
./doctotext//libdoctotext.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried

```
g++ -I./doctotext/ -L./doctotext/ -L/lib64/ -Wl,-rpath=./doctotext,-rpath=/lib64 -ldoctotext -lstdc++ -o example test_doctotext.cpp
```

, and I got the same errors (undefined reference).

libdoctotext.so indeed link to /lib64/libstdc++.so.6

```
[root@mail]~xian# ldd doctotext/libdoctotext.so | grep libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f96c7ab4000)
```

Fortunately, I found two method to solve this problem:

1. use newer gcc:
   I used gcc 9.1.1 (with scl), then `g++ -I./doctotext/ -L./doctotext/ -Wl,-rpath=./doctotext -ldoctotext  -o example test_doctotext.cpp` directly works.
2. specify the path to libstdc++.so.6 with gcc 4.4.7:
   `g++ -I./doctotext/ -L./doctotext/ -Wl,-rpath=./doctotext -ldoctotext /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -o example test_doctotext.cpp`

But I'm really curious about why my gcc 4.4.7 can not link to that libstdc++ under the system default path?

Is the version of libstdc++ be tightly coupled to the version of gcc in someway?

Comment: Why such an ancient version of GCC?

Comment: @tadman my server use Centos6 and gcc 4.4.7, due to some reasons I can't upgrade both of them...

Comment: Something that old is only going to have more and more problems as time goes on. You'll eventually have to upgrade or stick with the same build forever. Since it's 2020 you have lots of ways of fixing this, like using a container, instead of having to hand-tune the server.

Comment: If you *really* need to build something that links against older libraries it's best to do it in a VM, or a container where one and only one version of GCC is installed.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I've added it as a community wiki answer for now; feel free to post it yourself and ping me so I can remove the CW one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every GCC release is accompanied by its very own libstdc++ release.

The C++ standard library (and support libraries like libsupc++) often rely on specific implementation details in the compiler, including bugs, and specific changes in behaviour due to defect reports etc.
Sometimes even a new GCC release also needs a matching binutils (linker) release, as the way the code is generated changed to use a specific feature only available in the newer linker.

You can explicitly link it to the system libstdc++ by passing that path to the compiler/linker, but I don't recommend it, as the ABI may have changed in an incompatible way.

Comment: Isn't '-L/lib64 -lstdc++' also a way to explicitly link? Why it doesn't work, while '/lib64/libstdc++.so.6' works?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found gcc would use

```
[root@mail]/usr/lib64# find / -name "libstdc++.so"
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/32/libstdc++.so
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so
[root@mail]/usr/lib64# ll /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 37 Aug 21 15:22 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so -> ../../../../lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
```

6.0.13 doesn't have GLIBCXX_3.4.15

I re-link this to libstdc++.so.6.0.17, problem solved

Answer originally edited into the question by the OP, see [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64766212/2).