# Installed g++ with miniconda/conda-forge, can't compile hello world

Tags: c++, linux, g++, conda, conda-forge

This has something to do with a misconfiguration, but this is a brand new computer installed purely through miniconda/conda-forge, so it should work.

My miniconda configuration is super-simple: `conda-forge` is the only channel other than defaults (`~/.condarc`):

```
changeps1: false
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

It's up-to-date (`conda update --all`).

The GNU C, C++, and Fortran compilers have been installed through the [post-5.0 compiler environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html). Here are listings of `conda list linux`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/jpivarski/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.36.1               h193b22a_2    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.36                hf3e587d_33    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         9.3.0               h6df7d76_17  
gcc_linux-64              9.3.0               hf25ea35_33    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    9.3.0               hc4a2995_19    conda-forge
gfortran_linux-64         9.3.0               hdc58fab_33    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         9.3.0               hbdd7822_17  
gxx_linux-64              9.3.0               h3fbe746_33    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_14    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.36.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     9.3.0               hb95220a_17  
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  9.3.0               hf0c5c8d_17  
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_14    conda-forge
```

and `conda list compiler`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/jpivarski/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
c-compiler                1.2.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
compilers                 1.2.0                ha770c72_0    conda-forge
cxx-compiler              1.2.0                h4bd325d_0    conda-forge
fortran-compiler          1.2.0                h1990efc_0    conda-forge
```

and `conda list binutil`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/jpivarski/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
binutils                  2.36.1               hdd6e379_2    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.36.1               h193b22a_2    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.36                hf3e587d_33    conda-forge
```

This is a Debian system, and it came with a package named `gcc-8-base` installed,

```
gcc-8-base/stable,now 8.3.0-6 amd64 [installed]
```

but that package didn't add a `gcc` command to the path, so it's not user-visible. This Debian is in a Crostini VM on a Chromebook (`/proc/version`):

```
Linux version 5.4.119-14943-gff839c7fedcc (chrome-bot@chromeos-ci-legacy-us-east1-d-x32-83-pa8b) (Chromium OS 12.0_pre422132_p20210405-r4 clang version 13.0.0 (/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/llvm-12.0_pre422132_p20210405-r4/work/llvm-12.0_pre422132_p20210405/clang cd442157cff4aad209ae532cbf031abbe10bc1df)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 28 21:06:01 PDT 2021
```

Now, the fun part. Here's the simplest C++ program imaginable:

```cpp
// #include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int x = 2 + 4;
  // std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

(Yes, I commented out "hello world" when it didn't work.)

Compiling it with any of the following:

```sh
g++ tmp.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 tmp.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -lstdc++ tmp.cpp
```

yields

```
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `aligned_alloc@GLIBC_2.16'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Incidentally, with `ldd /that/long/path/to/libstdc++.so`:

```
./../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2e8d1000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ef64da8e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ef64d8cd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ef64dd92000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ef64d8b3000)
```

nothing is "not found."

I can compile the above program (with commented-out "hello world") using `gcc`:

```sh
gcc -std=c++11 tmp.cpp
```

but if I put the `#include <iostream>` and `std::cout` back in, the compiler errors are:

```
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8BE1Tc.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout' in read-only section `.text'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8BE1Tc.o: in function `main':
tmp.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `std::cout'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: tmp.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: tmp.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: tmp.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8BE1Tc.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tmp.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: tmp.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/home/jpivarski/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How could it have gotten so misconfigured, and how to fix it? This is a *fresh installation*. Nothing weird has happened yet. If this should be a bug report to conda-forge, I don't know where to post it.

Comment: `gcc` fails because it links against `c` libraries, but those don't include `std::cout`.  As to the rest maybe this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766212/old-gcc-can-not-automatically-find-the-new-version-libstdc. You can try `gcc` with explicitly linking `-lstdc++`, but this is quite weird.

Comment: Isn't that what my third attempt was: `g++ -std=c++11 -lstdc++ tmp.cpp`? Maybe a `-L` is needed to point at the right directory for `libstdc++.so`, in case it's picking up the wrong one...

Comment: Oh sorry, I was specifically referring to the final lines of `gcc` compilation. It seems `g++` finds the libraries, but something weird is going on with the linker in `GLIBC`

Comment: Maybe you don't have the right GLIBC version installed . I think ldd --version will tell you that.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer:** I installed it from scratch again, and this time it works.

Since I can't try the two side-by-side (this was on a Chromebook with limited disk space, so that wasn't an option), I can only speculate about the cause, based on what was different this time:

1. I installed all of the low-level `gcc_linux-64`, `gxx_linux-64`, etc. and the high-level `compilers`, `c-compiler`, `cxx-compiler` in a single "`conda install`" command, rather than in separate commands.
2. I added `channel_priority: strict` to my `~/.condarc` configuration.

The only reason that I didn't use the high-level `compilers` package (and let it pull in `gcc_linux-64`, `gxx_linux-64`, etc. as dependencies) is because I didn't know about it. In my first installation attempt, I installed `gcc_linux-64` and `gxx_linux-64`, which added them as executables accessible through `CC` and `CXX` environment variables, but not on the path as `gcc` and `g++`. Then, when I realized that the `compilers` package was intended for user-facing `gcc` and `g++` (through `c-compiler` and `cxx-compiler`), I installed that afterward. It's possible that there's a broken assumption in the dependencies among these, since `conda install` is supposed to make all of these packages consistent with each other (especially after `conda update --all`). That's speculation #1.

The second attempt was also different because I added `channel_priority: strict`, following [instructions I found on conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge). Apparently, the argument for strict priority is so strong that it's going to become the default in conda 5.0. Maybe my first attempt mixed conda-forge and defaults? (If so, I don't know why I've never had this problem before—strict priority is new to me, though I've only ever used two channels.) That's speculation #2, and I believe it more strongly than speculation #1.

For completeness, I also did the second attempt with [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba), rather than conda (limited CPU power; didn't have time to wait), though I don't believe that could make a difference. If it does, that's bad news for either conda or mamba.

I'm leaving this question-and-answer pair up for posterity, in case anyone else runs into an issue that looks like this. (If you do, you might be able to add data to resolve the ambiguity above.)